# Как сделать кнопку активной при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы после загрузки страницы первая кнопка уже была в активном состоянии, как это сделать?

```html
<ul class="advantage-list">
  <li class="advantage-list__item">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="item-link" id="btn">
            <span class="item-link__text">Доставка</span>
          </button>
  </li>
  <li class="advantage-item-garante">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="item-link">
            <span class="item-link__text">Гарантия</span>
         </button>
  </li>
  <li class="advantage-item-credit">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="item-link">
            <span class="item-link__textbig">Кредит</span>
          </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: onload или DOMContentLoaded события js

Comment: `<button type="button"...` Что за масло масляное?

Comment: @UModeL, вообще-то в форме по умолчанию будет `type=submit`, так что всё верно написано.

Comment: В коде не показано ничего, из-за чего она была бы недоступной.

Comment: @Qwertiy: про формы тоже ни слова ;-) A в IE было по-другому кажется... Пойду доки перечитаю...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
  alert('Кнопка')
};
```

```html
<ul class="advantage-list">
  <li class="advantage-list__item">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="item-link" id="btn">
        <span class="item-link__text">Доставка</span>
      </button>
  </li>
  <li class="advantage-item-garante">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="item-link">
        <span class="item-link__text">Гарантия</span>
     </button>
  </li>
  <li class="advantage-item-credit">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="item-link">
        <span class="item-link__textbig">Кредит</span>
      </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```